# WebMock.disable_net_connect! not working with rspec (no VCR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webmock

I tried to put `WebMock.disable_net_connect!` in a lot of places but as recommended in my last test I put it in `spec_helper.rb` like this:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

My spec is the following:

```
describe Client do
  describe '#get_something' do
    context 'when post params are valid' do
      it 'returns a response' do
        request = stub_request(:post, 'https://myurl.com')
          .to_return(my_response)

        result = client.get_something(params)

        expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:post, 'https://myurl.com')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hmm, of course that my client makes the call:

```
class Client
  def get_something(params)
    RestClient.post @url, params
  end
end
```

It fails with this message:

```
Failure/Error: end
       The request GET https://myurl.com/ was expected to execute 1 time but it executed 0 times

       The following requests were made:

       No requests were made.
       ============================================================
```

I'm using rails 4.1.8, rspec 3.1.7, rspec-rails 3.1.0 and webmock 1.8.11. Right now, I'm creating a mock of a http_client to get things working, but, any help here will be appreciated! If you need more information just let me know!

Comment: Could you try `expect(request).to have_been_requested` ?

Comment: @HoMan already tried and I get the same error. The thing is that `disable_net_connect` is not working, so the stubed request never is requested...

Comment: Ahhh. I guess since the allow_localhost is dependent on url. Try changing `https://myurl.com` to `localhost:3000` or something

Comment: Actually, I want that assert that I'm not calling localhost.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `disable_net_connect` then? Perhaps `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` instead?

Comment: I'll try it, @HoMan!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this instead:

`WebMock.allow_net_connect!`

Alternatively, you could also do

`WebMock.disable_net_connect(allow: ['https://myurl.com'])`

As shown in the documentation of WebMock:

```
WebMock.allow_net_connect!

stub_request(:any, "www.example.com").to_return(:body => "abc")

Net::HTTP.get('www.example.com', '/')    # ===> "abc"
```

Comment: As far I understood this is the default behavior I don't even need to use `WebMock.allow_net_connect!`. I want to do the same done here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests

Comment: `WebMock.disable_net_connect(allow: ['https://myurl.com'])` will only allow https://myurl.com to pass through though?

Answer (score 0):

Putting these two lines before making api call to external host solved the issue for me.

```
  WebMock.disable!
  WebMock.disable_net_connect!
```

See this for more details: https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/897